# Sip Call(android)

Tags: android, sip

Пытаюсь реализовать sip телефонию, нашел в документации [пример](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#manager) и решил делать по нему

Но, в итоге я получаю

```
android.net.sip.SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?
```

Ниже предоставлен исходный код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public SipManager mSipManager = null;
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
String name,domain,sipAddress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    name = "name";
    domain = "domain.ru";
    sipAddress = "adress@adress.ru";
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
    if(mSipManager == null) {
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    try {
        builder = new SipProfile.Builder(name, domain);
        builder.setPassword("VEiVHXAyBDvtGbUD");
        mSipProfile = builder.build();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);


        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                Log.d("SIP:", "onRegistering");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                Log.d("SIP:", "onRegistrationDone");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("SIP:", "onRegistrationFailed");
            }
        });

        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                Log.d("SIP:", "onCallEnded");
            }
        };

        mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener,30);
        Log.d("SIP:", "MakeAudioCall");
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("SIP:", "SipException");
    }
}
```

Исключение получаю  после

> mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener,30);